# How to Make Sorting Macro continues if Column A value change

Tags: excel

hello i am having this vb code for sorting macro for my table. I want to make this code continuously updated if the value in column A change (Date). Can anyone help me out?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

Range("A6:K6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash Flow").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash Flow").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("A6"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash Flow").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Change(..)` should be what you are looking for...

Comment: Tried worksheet_Change() but not able to run the macro automatically if any value in table is changed.

Comment: Further to that all cells in table are having VLookup so what i want as soon as the date is changed in Column A using VLOOKUP entire table need to be sort automatically.